# Exclude List of document in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

How can I exclude(using Id) List of document in collections using mongoose .

```
User.find({}, function (err, docs) {

})
```

It gives all document in user Collection but I need to exclude list of doc from user collection

```
excludedUserId = ["234h2gl2422vb2c3sdf","sdf98sfd9sfdu978fsf","sfdsdf2325yh3432",......] //dummy User Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$nin` field operator. Example:

```
{_id:{$nin:[ObjectId('5f3de9dca1aaae489a9620e0'),...]}}
```